# register=template.library() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I have writen a custom filter to show the number of products that has been added to cart page.
here's custom filter cart_tags.py

```
from django import template
from order.models import Order

register=template.library()

@register.filter(name="cart_total")
def cart_total(user):
    order=Order.objects.filter(user=user,ordered=False) 
    if order.exists():
        return order[0].orderitems.count()
    else:
        return 0
```

navbar.html to show the use the filter

```
{% load cart_tags %}
<li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{% url 'cart' %}" class="nav-link">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart
              <span class="badge badge-light">{{ request.user | cart_total}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

I have also created **init**.py in templatetags folder.
But it shows me this error in terminal

```
 File "C:\Users\ITS\Desktop\my-e-com-project\E_commerce\order\templatetags\cart_tags.py", line 4, in <module>
    register=template.library()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Help me with this please

Comment: please try instead `register = template.Library()` -- note the capitalization which is the *class* and not the module.

Comment: It's `Library` (with Uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, It looks like there's a small mistake in your code. The correct name for the method you want to use is "Library", not "library" just use upper case letter for l and your problem should be solved!